# How do you use JSP Tag Files in a Sling bundle?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, aem, sling

I am trying to create a bundle installed in sling and use a custom TagLib. Instead of using a java class extending TagSupport, I want to use a tag file. This way i can use a Sling Model to represent the JCR and a JSP tag file to represent the markup.

Here's my Tag File, It's a very basic anchor, nothing special, I am just trying to test stuff out:

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" %>
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ tag import="org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource, CallToAction" %>
<%@ attribute name="resource" rtexprvalue="true" required="true" type="org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource" %>

<%
    CallToAction cta = resource.adaptTo(CallToAction.class);
    jspContext.setAttribute("cta", cta);
%>
<jsp:doBody var="bodytext">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty bodytext }">
        <c:set var="text" value="${bodytext}" />
</c:when>
    <c:when test="${not empty cta.text}">
        <c:set var="text" value="${cta.text}" />
</c:when>
</c:choose>

<a class="${cta.css}" href="${cta.href}" title="${cta.title}" >${text}</a>
```

I created a TLD file, which I tried in both the WEB-INF/tags and META-INF/tags folder (i stripped out the xmlns, but the file is valid and works).:

```
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>test</short-name>
<uri>http://www.example.com/taglibs/test/1.0</uri>
<tag-file>
    <description>
        Creates an anchor (&lt;a&gt;) HTML element according to the description in 
        CallToAction
    </description>
    <name>cta</name>
    <path>/WEB-INF/tags/cta.tag</path>
</tag-file>
```

I use it in a JSP like so:

```
<test:cta resource="${resource}"  />
```

I have the Maven Bundle plugin configured appropriately. I have tried:

- /META-INF
- /META-INF/tags
- /WEB-INF
- /WEB-INF/tags

According to this: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sling-dev/200901.mbox/%3C49750256.7040704@oracle.com%3E

```
<Bundle-Resource>/WEB-INF</Bundle-Resource>
<Sling-Bundle-Resource>/WEB-INF</Sling-Bundle-Resource>
```

However, no matter what I do, I get the following error:

> org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:
>   org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException:
>   /apps/example/calltoaction/calltoaction.jsp(1,1) File "/WEB-INF/tags/cta.tag"
>   not found

So, my question is: can you actually use a **jsp tag** file in this manner, in Sling? My goal was to not have a Java class actually rendering markup, via print writer commands. But it seems my work is in vain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of your code is flawed. But it is definitely possible. I've successfully written several tags using tag files and wrapped them in an osgi bundle for deployment in cq, some rather complex (like a google maps component with kml support for example, or printing out a recursive navigation starting from a path or resource).

Before going into detail, I'm going to make the following assumptions

1. You know how to setup a maven project and work with poms
2. You know how to configure a bundle in a pom for deployment in osgi
3. You are familiar with how bundles work and you know about Activators
4. You know how to work with JSTL, tagslibs and tagfiles

I have a taglib project which has the following configuration for a specific tag using a tagfile.

In my taglib project I have my tld at /src/main/resources/META-INF/my-taglib.tld

The contents are similar but I used some different config, translated to your example this would come to

```
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
 <tlib-version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</tlib-version>
 <short-name>test</short-name>
 <uri>http://www.example.com/my-taglib</uri>
 <tag-file>
  <name>cta</name>
  <path>/META-INF/tags/cta.tag</path>
 </tag-file>
</taglib>
```

The actual tag file is located under /src/main/resources/META-INF/tags/cta.tag

I dont like scriptlets, so I would use the appropriate [sling tag lib](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-scripting-jsp-taglib.html) for the adaptTo. Also I didn't see any specific package for your CallToAction class, so I put it in the fictional package com.company.models.CallToAction. The file this in your case:

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" isELIgnored="false" display-name="CallToAction" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ attribute name="resource" rtexprvalue="true" required="true"
          type="org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource" %>

<c:set var="cta" value="${sling:adaptTo(resource,'com.company.models.CallToAction')}" />
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${not empty cta.text}">
      <c:set var="text" value="${cta.text}" />
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      <c:set var="text" value="${cta.href}" />
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<a class="${cta.css}" href="${cta.href}" title="${cta.title}" >${text}</a>
```

I assume you have your maven dependencies set correctly to make your CallToAction class available to this maven project. My maven plugins for generating the taglib in the pom looks like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.squeakysand.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsptld-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <shortName>test</shortName>
        <processTagFiles>true</processTagFiles>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-Activator>company.project.taglib.osgi.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
            <Include-Resource>META-INF/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.tld=${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.tld,{maven-resources}
            </Include-Resource>
            <Sling-Bundle-Resources>/META-INF/tags</Sling-Bundle-Resources>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This worked as expected. All of your assumptions were correct. the reason I don't use the taglib syntax for the adaptTo functionality, is that the vanilla AEM 5.6.1 instance has v2.1.8 of the Sling Taglibs and the adaptTo is in v2.2.0.

The issue I found was a lack of pluralization on the Sling-Bundle-Resource pom definition:

`<Sling-Bundle-Resoruces>/META-INF/tags</Sling-Bundle-Resources>`

Not

`<Sling-Bundle-Resoruce>/META-INF/tags</Sling-Bundle-Resource>`